# Generate code from deployed files

Tags: soap, glassfish, glassfish-4, recover, war

I had mistakely deleted my web services code. I don't have any backup of this code. Tried some file recovery tools but it didn't work. I have deployed the project in glass fish 4.0 server and the application works fine from there. So I am thinking is there any way I can generate the codes of that webservice? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the application deployed in your glassfish server then it is possible. You can always find your the `.class` files of original codes (not the one compiled by SEI) inside your domain folder of glassfish. Then you can use some third party tools to generate java codes from the class files. There are to ways that you can deploy your application in the glass fish server:-

1. By using the glass fish server web GUI and deploy it.
2. By using exernal IDE like eclipse where you create the glassfish server and deploy it.

For condition 1, goto :-

`glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\__internal`

where domain1 is your domain name. By default it is the name of your domain

For condition2, goto:-

`glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\eclipseApps`

where domain1 is your domain name. By default it is the name of your domain

You can find your java codes inside `WEB-INF\classes` inside your project name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And you have tools that can generate java codes from `.class` files don't you?